# Update collection with $in clause mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a mongo collection I need to update (around 120k documents) and I have an array of values I want to take as a filter to match documents to update.
For every document, I need to add the same property with the same value.

Is that possible to use the $in clause in mongodb in an update query to achieve that ?

Right now, I'm just looping through my array of values and updating my documents one at a time and it doesn't feel right.

```
let ps = ["user1", "user2"]; // my array
for(let i = 0; i < ps.length; i++){
  // my function that updates on document and adds a property to it.
  await Partname.update_partname(ps[i], "has_image", true);
}
```

That is basically what I want to achieve :

```
db.getCollection('partnames').update({
  user: {
      $in: ["user1", "user2"]
  }
}, "has_image", true)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: To do what? Are you expecting to update 120K specific documents with the same value? Or are you expecting to update the same amount of documents with "specific values" to each matching selected document only? Two very distinctively different questions, and you two sentences really do not clearly state which of those you want. You really need to elaborate here. Also removing meaningless tags from your post. Tags define your audience who can actually answer your question. MongoDB is a "database" and yes you want to "update", but neither of these are valid tags for people specialized to answer.

Comment: Probably more to the point. Please show a sample of code you actually attempted in order to achieve what you want. Even if it does not work ( if it did, then you would not be asking ) it still serves a purpose of at least loosely demonstrating what you expected to happen here. This is often very useful for people to use as a guide to answer your question, as it is at least reasonably clear what you "expected" to happen.

Comment: I just updated my post, thanks for your feedback.

Comment: And the part where you actually tried to use `$in`? And was there any specific problem? This is the title of your question, but none of the demonstrated code attempts to do this. Please don't ask "Can I do this?". Just try and do it, and if there is a problem, then just post what that problem is.

Comment: do you need to **match some specific docs** with `$in operator`? what is the condition for matching? Or you just want to update all 120K docs?

Comment: I need to match some specific docs, on a specific property. I updated the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things here,

**1.** If you have a **schema** for your collection, then

Make sure you **update the schema** to have `"has_image"` field with the proper type, then fire your query.

use this query:

```
db.collection("logs").update({"users": {$in: ["user1", "user2"]}},
      {$set:{"has_image": true}},
      {multi: true},
      (err, data) =>{
          //todo
      })
```

the key here is to use **`multi: true`** option for update query that lets you update multiple documents at once.

also, you have to use `$set` in the update query.

**2.** If you don't have any schema for collection, then

You are free, just fire the above query.

> **Suggestion:**
>
> If the values in the array you are going to use in $in the
> operator are **ids** (which are ObjectId in the collection) of the user,
> then make sure you **convert them to ObjectId** first.